# Sorting styled dataframe return keyError in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-styles

I would like to `groupby` and `sortindex` upon styling a `dataframe`. However, the compiler return an error

```
KeyError: ('Other', 'B')
```

May I know what is the issue here?

```
The code to reproduce the above error:



import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
dict_map=dict(group_one=['D','GG','G'],group_two=['A','C','E','F'])
vv=np.random.randn(5, 4)
# ['foo', '*', 'bar','ff']
nn=np.array([['foo', '*', 'bar','ff'], ['foo', '*', 'bar','**'],
             ['foo', '*', 'bar','**'],['foo', '*', 'bar','ff'],
             ['foo', '*', '**','ff']])
arrays = [["bar", "bar", "baz", "baz"],
          ["one", "two", "one", "two"]]
tuples = list(zip(*arrays))

index = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(tuples, names=["first", "second"])
df = pd.DataFrame(nn, index=["A", "B", "C","D",'G'], columns=index)
df = df.rename_axis ( index=['my_ch'] ).reset_index()

d = {i:k for k,v in dict_map.items() for i in v}
out = df.assign(Group=df.xs("my_ch",axis=1).map(d).fillna('Other'))


def highlight_(s):
    return np.select(
        condlist=[s.str.contains('\*\*'), s.str.contains('\*')],
        choicelist=['background-color:green', 'background-color:purple'],
        default='')

df=out.style.apply(highlight_)


df.data=df.data.set_index(['Group', 'my_ch'])

df.data=df.data.sort_index(level=0)
df.to_excel('n1test.xlsx')
```

Please note that, in actual use case. sorting the index `level 0` is required

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np


dict_map = dict(group_one=["D", "GG", "G"], 
                group_two=["A", "C", "E", "F"])
vv = np.random.randn(5, 4)
nn = np.array(
    [
        ["foo", "*", "bar", "ff"],
        ["foo", "*", "bar", "**"],
        ["foo", "*", "bar", "**"],
        ["foo", "*", "bar", "ff"],
        ["foo", "*", "**", "ff"],
    ]
)
arrays = [["bar", "bar", "baz", "baz"], ["one", "two", "one", "two"]]
tuples = list(zip(*arrays))

index = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(tuples, names=["first", "second"])
df = pd.DataFrame(nn, index=["A", "B", "C", "D", "G"], columns=index)
df = df.rename_axis(index=["my_ch"]).reset_index()

d = {i: k for k, v in dict_map.items() for i in v}
out = df.assign(Group=df.xs("my_ch", axis=1).map(d).fillna("Other"))


def highlight_(s):
    return np.select(
        condlist=[s.str.contains("\*\*"), s.str.contains("\*")],
        choicelist=["background-color:green", "background-color:purple"],
        default=None,
    )


(
    out.sort_index(level=0)
    .set_index(["Group", "my_ch"])
    .style.apply(highlight_)
    .to_excel("n1test.xlsx")
)
```

The main difference is to sort first then set the index then apply the Styler and save it as an Excel file. All expressions are enclosed in the parenthesis instead of break lines.

Comment: Please explain changes you made?

Comment: I did a modification trying to explain it. The other changes are only format changes.

Comment: Im  just curios why enclosing the routine solve the issue?

Comment: It's not the enclosing, it's the style data indexing.